# SciPy will not import while trying to run DM script

Tags: python, scipy, dm-script

I am having an issue with SciPy not importing properly in my DM script. The script will get stuck on the "import scipy" line. I installed scipy using miniconda, have tried reinstalling with no success.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the *latest* GMS version currenlty available from the homepage (GMS 3.4.1.2938 (FreeAnalytical2.zip) )? It's always helpful to cite such things in a question.

Comment: In general, it's advisable to do the following in such situations: Go into the Anaconda Prompt and GMS_VENV_PYTHON environment and start the Python interpreter there. Then run the same script. Sometimes, additional warning/error messages appear that are not posted from within the GMS environment. That can help identifying the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to import scipy in another compiler such as Spyder or Jupyter notebook, if it can be imported properly, then check the checkbox of "Execute on Background Thread" in GMS is not to be selected (see the figure below). I can import the scipy and sklearn by doing this.
For your reference.

[image]

Comment: If you discover that a Python script *must not* be executed on a Background Thread, you can actually check for this in the Python script itself, using the command `DM.IsScriptOnMainThread()`

Answer (score 0):

(Windows) I have found that on my system using pip as recommended (via pip install x) does not work for any package, however using conda as *not recommended* (via conda install) in the command prompt allowed me to install scipy for GMS.

Also make sure you start the command prompt in administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

DM uses C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\GMS_VENV_PYTHON for Phyton environment, so you should install scipy there, I don't know how select that location to install, so I

1. install Miniconda3 in a folder "user\Miniconda3"
2. Run AnacondaPromt(miniconda3) and install scipy by run "conda install scipy"
3. copy content of "user\Miniconda3" folder to "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\GMS_VENV_PYTHON"